# How to define the type of a named function?

Tags: typescript, syntax

```
function Foo(): string {}
```

Means a `Foo` is a function that returns a `string`.

```
interface SFC {
    (props: Props): any;
}

const Foo: SFC = p => {};
```

Means that `Foo` is an anonymous function matching the signature `SFC` and `p` is of type `Props`.

How can I declare `function Foo()` that matches `SFC`? What's the syntax?

i.e., I want to declare a function using the `function` keyword (not `const`) and the function itself is of type `SFC`.

---

These don't work:

```
function Foo: SFC () {}
function Foo() {}: SFC
```

Comment: For React, you can use `React.ComponentProps` to get the props and type your component that way. For the return value, there's [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) built into TS. Also [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype).

Comment: I've been looking for the same thing, but it doesn't seem to be available.  Just have to live with separately giving types to props and return type for now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a number of TypeScript proposals for explicitly typing a function declared as a named, hoisted function (as opposed to an expression). None of them have been implemented yet. [#22063](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22063) seems to be the most active.

- [#16918](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16918): (Proposal) syntax for contextual typing of a function declaration
- **[#22063](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22063): Suggestion: Type annotations and interfaces for function declarations**

  - Dupe [#37433](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37433): Add mechanism for specifying the type of a function declaration
  - Dupe [#39419](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39419): Allow function declarations to be typed
  - Dupe [#40455](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40455): Provide a way to indicate that a function declaration conforms to some interface/type
- [#34319](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34319): Describe function signature using an interface

  - Dupe [#39039](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39039): A syntax for function declarations to "implement" types (like `const C: React.FC<Props> = (props0) => ...`)
- [#40378](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40378): Type Cast or Assertions on the FunctionDeclaration

The release of the `satisfies` keyword in TypeScript 4.9 ([#47920](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920), [#46827](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/46827)) is related, but only applies to expressions; it does not change function definitions. Open issue [#51556](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51556) claims to follow up on #47920 with `satisfies` on functions, with [#52195](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52195) duped against it.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript uses [duck typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html), so the `Foo` function is of type `SFC` if their structure matches.

```
interface SFC {
    (props: any): any;
}

function Foo(props: any): any {
    console.log(props);
}

let sfc: SFC = Foo; // Foo is of type SFC.
sfc("Foo");
```

Comment: That wasn't the answer I was looking for, but I guess it's the one I needed to hear. This actually works well enough for my needs. I just wanted to impose a type on props, and then the function itself will still be an `SFC` so it'll pass my other type checks. Good stuff! I don't get any checking on the return type if I do it this way though. i.e., it won't check that I didn't screw up the function definition.

Comment: I am not sure about what you said. You can specify other types for the props.

Comment: The question is asking how the entire function can be typed, rather than having to manually type the params and return values.

Answer (score -3):

> I want to declare a function using the function keyword (not const) and the function itself is of type SFC.

You can't. And you shouldn't, since `const` gives you all you need.

## `name` property

Good browsers will add that for you e.g. chrome.

[image]

Comment: Are they 100% equivalent? Will the TSX compiler add `displayName` to React stateless functional components declared in this manner?

Comment: I didn't think anonymous functions got names, but apparently [they do](https://gist.github.com/mnpenner/3e112138dfb3ba6f49662b51ec60726e), but not when they're like *really* anonymous (wrapped an IIFE and not assigned to a var).

Comment: You can name the function also, like: `const Foo: SFC = function Foo() {};`

Comment: added a note on `name` 

Comment: I'd question whether or not that's giving a name to the function or the reference-what happens if you make bar reference foo? What's the name then? (Not on device with decent browser or if check.)

Comment: It should also be noted the `const`s aren't hoisted, so these are really not the same.

Comment: I am sorry @basarat, I love your typescript book but I don't agree with this answer. First of all there's hoisting issue and the second, in context of React, it is more verbose to assign function to var just to have it typed. 
Also please not that react team uses `function` keyword in their examples so it might be confusing for people coming from JS world because suddenly you need rewrite your function components

Comment: Hoisting is a big deal; by using arrow functions assigned to variables you lose the ability to reorder your code from highest to lowest abstraction. You can call a function before you declare it, but arrow functions must be declared first. A consequence of this is that you end up having modules ordered from lowest to highest abstraction, which means you have to wade through a bunch of small utility functions to get to the meat of the module. This is terrible for readability and comprehension, and the recent trend of using arrow functions for everything is a blight on javascript codebases.