# How to apply a function type to a function declaration

Tags: typescript

Given the following type:

```js
type Add = (x:number, y:number) => number
```

I can declare a `const` of that type and define the rest of the function without having to specify the types explicitly. Typescript knows that `x` is a number and `y` is a number.

```js
const add: Add = (x, y) => x + y;
```

I prefer to define functions using `function` rather than `const` however there doesn't appear to be a way to type the complete function declaration. It appears that you are forced to define the parameters and the return type separately. Is there any way to use the `Add` type on the declaration below so that I don't have to specify that `x` is a number and `y` is a number

```js
function add(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

without being forced to do something like

```js
function add(x: Parameters<Add>[0], y: Parameters<Add>[1]): ReturnType<Add> {
    return x + y;
}
```

Comment: Only thing I can think of is a compromise `const add: Add = function add(x, y)`

Comment: You can also do `(…args: Parameters<Add>)`

Comment: @CertainPerformance how to use this with generics? e.g. Add<T>

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't specify types for function declarations. You can only use `Parameters` and `ReturnType`. The only minor improvement would be to use destructuring for the parameters:

```
type Add = (x:number, y:number) => number
function add(...[x, y]: Parameters<Add>): ReturnType<Add> {
    return x + y;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnKBeKAKAHgLgHYFcC2ARhAE4A0UIOBxJAlMgHxR5GkBQAZrtgMbABLAPbYoAQwSoAdDIDa6CiAC6mKAAUxJMfgjBSAZwA88OIzqqASrtwlsAFXARjCZgG92UT1BLXbUdFAA1JQA3OwAvkA)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify types for function expressions but not function declarations.

```
// index.d.ts
export function add(a: string, b: string): string;
export function add(a: number, b: number): number;
```

```js
// index.js
/**
 * @typedef {import('./index.d.ts').add} AddFunction
 */

/**
 * @type AddFunction
 * @param {any} a
 * @param {any} b
 */
export const add = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

add(1, 2);
add('a', 'b');
add(1, '2')
```

```bash
❯ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc
index.js:16:1 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(a: string, b: string): string', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(a: number, b: number): number', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.

16 add(1, '2');
   ~~~~~~~~~~~

Found 1 error in index.js:16
```

[Playground Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-gff3p1?file=index.js)